# How to use group a collection in Backbone.js by an array attribute in each model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, collections, group-by, underscore.js

I got a collection where each model has an attribute 'names' that contains an array of names. I want to group by each name. Each model could have plenty of names.

My code

```
groupByName: function(){
 return this.collection.groupBy(function(item){
   for (var i=0; i<item.get('names').length; i++){
      return item.get('names')[i]['description']; //description: get name by id
   }
 });
},
```

The problem, is that with this code, the groupBy just groups by the first name of each array cause of the return breaks the for-loop.

Any idea??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `names` array does not contain duplicate entries, perhaps something like:

```
groupByName: function () {
  var grouped = {};
  this.collection.each(function (item) {
    var names = item.get('names');
    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
      var description = names[i].description;
      var group = grouped[description] || (grouped[description] = []);
      group.push(item);
    }
  });
  return grouped;
}
```